# How to check a button was clicked without overried onclick method?

Tags: java, android, button, onclick, overriding

This is my MainActivity, button and onclick function:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText etName;
    Button btSubmit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        etName = findViewById(R.id.et_name);
        btSubmit = findViewById(R.id.bt_submit);
        AwesomeValidation awesomeValidation = new AwesomeValidation(ValidationStyle.BASIC);
        awesomeValidation.addValidation(this, R.id.et_name, RegexTemplate.NOT_EMPTY, R.string.invalid_name);

        btSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openSubActivityEmty();
                if (awesomeValidation.validate()) {
                    //On success
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Form Validate Succefull..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Submit faild!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Now i'm trying write a new class which use to find the button and check if the button was click one more time?

So can i do this or someone has any solution for this task?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to track a click without overriding the onClick method. If you want to check if the button is clicked you can just add a boolean variable isClicked and make it false by default. Inside the onClick, make it true. If you want to access it from a different class, make it public.

Comment: i'm building a sdk for every app. So i can not edit the app's source code :((